# writing a spelling test for java and can't get my code to work the word abstract keeps messing up the whole thing

Tags: java

i have been looking for hour on how to fix my code to make it work.
i am writing a spelling text the shows the user a definition and make them spell the word.
in my if else statement, the word abstract keeps me from moving on. the code is really long so i will give you a little bit of it.
i left comments near the bottom.

```
class SpellingExam {
    static CinReader cn = new CinReader();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Tim";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
        String theDate = df.format(today);
        String goodWords = "Method, String, Java";
        String content = name + "\r\n" + theDate + "\r\n" + goodWords;
        stringToFile( content, "Spelling exam for " + name + ".txt" );
    }

    private static void stringToFile( String content, String fileName ) {
        try {
            File file = new File( fileName );
            if ( !file.exists() ) {
                file.createNewFile( );
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( file.getAbsoluteFile( ) );
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );
            bw.write( content );
            bw.close( );
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }

    public static void question1() {
        System.out.println("A class with the abstract reserved word in its header. Abstract classes are distinguished by the fact that you may not directly construct objects from them using the new operator. An abstract class may have zero or more abstract methods.");
        char answer1 = cn.readChar();
        if("abstract") {
           /*
            * here is the main problem
            * the word abstract is highlighted
            * incompatible types is all it says
            */
            System.out.println("correct!");
            playerScore += 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("incorrect...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In If statement, one can only use boolean. Here you are using "abstract" which is string. I am assuming that you have posted all the  relevnt bits of code.

Comment: He might wanted to write something like BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(cn); if(cn.readLine().equals("abstract"))

Answer (score 0):

vijar's and Ale Zalazar's comments are correct.  There's no boolean condition for your if() statement to match.  You need to read the user's typed input and compare that input with the String you expect.